# Neo4j: Copy folder to /data Directory via Shell-Script in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, shell, docker, neo4j, copy

I want to build a Docker image based on the official Neo4j image.

In the Dockerfile, I am adding a shell script to the image, which I execute in the next step in the Dockerfile.

In this shell script, I want to copy a folder into the data directory (/var/lib/neo4j/data which is linked to /data). However, this does not work. There is no error statement, but the folder does not exist in the data-directory.

`cp -r wikipediadb /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/wikipediadb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, if anybody should ever have the same problem: I figured out, that removing the directory and newly creating it works. Then you can copy the folder without any problems:

`RUN rm -r /var/lib/neo4j/data
RUN mkdir /var/lib/neo4j/data
RUN mkdir /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
RUN cp -r wikipediadb /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/wikipediadb`